# Prestashop 1.7 display parent category in category tree

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I'm looking for solution to display parent category in category tree right above current category in Prestashop 1.7.6.8.

Here's a screenshot explaining more:

[categorytreeimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVIbB.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This can be found in the module Faceted search if i understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is already implemented in the native category tree module,
just configure it as follows :

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work when depth of category is at this point and earlier:
https://prnt.sc/135zh11

But works at this point:
https://prnt.sc/135zkn4

Any clue why?